# Returning non sequential records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a gridview displaying filtered records, that is to say, there are gaps in primary key `ID`.

The filter is applied typically on 3 columns:

```
dev_ID (nvarchar)
date
code_ID (nvarchar)
```

and a random 4th column which will not be filtered in the next query.

When a gridview record is selected,

I would like to return to the `DB` and get the 10 records before and after the selected gridview record

(I can start with the `PK` in this instance).

These records may still `NOT` be sequential on primary key `ID` and based on other factors,

there may not be 10 records before or 10 records after.

The new query should return the 10 records before and after selected record,

where dev_ID = @x, code_Id = @y and date = @someDate.

CURRENT:

I am able to return the results required in two seperate queries but am not able to combine them into a single resultset.

```
( SELECT TOP 10
            tblData.*
  FROM      tblData
  WHERE     pk <= 5481
        AND dev_ID = 'REC1'
        AND code_ID = 'FMU'
        AND CAST(event_date_time AS DATE) = '10/18/2013'
  ORDER BY  pk DESC
)
UNION
( SELECT TOP 10
            tblData.*
   FROM      tblData
  WHERE     pk >= 5481
            AND dev_ID = 'REC1'
            AND code_ID = 'FMU'
            AND CAST(event_date_time AS DATE) = '10/18/2013'
  ORDER BY  pk ASC
)
```

Could really use some help on this part. thanks

UPDATE:

I have moved to this approach and could use a bit of help....

```
WITH NumberedMyTable AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PK) AS RowNumber, *
FROM
    tblData
WHERE dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMC' AND CAST(date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013'
)
SELECT *  
FROM
    NumberedMyTable
WHERE
    ((**SELECT RowNumber FROM NumberedMyTable WHERE PK = 5481)** BETWEEN RowNumber + 10 AND   RowNumber - 10)
```

This cuurently is not returning any records.

How can i query the `RowNumber`

for use in the `WHERE` clause to return the desired range, the BOLDED portion?

Orig effort:

```
WITH    recs
      AS ( SELECT TOP 1
                    *
           FROM     tblData
           WHERE    pk = GDV_PK
           ORDER BY pk
         ),
    r AS ( SELECT TOP 10
                    tblData.*
           FROM     tblData
           WHERE    dev_ID = @x
                    AND code_ID = @y
           ORDER BY PK DESC
         )
SELECT TOP 10
        *
FROM    tblData
WHERE   dev_ID = ( SELECT   dev_ID
                   FROM     r
                 )
        AND CAST(date_time AS DATE) = @someDate
ORDER BY pk
```

Comment: so tblTelematicData is the table that holds the 21 records you want?

Comment: Sorry, no tblData, fixing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally produced a working solution, posting it here for anyone else that may comes accros this....

```
Select * From
(SELECT TOP 10 tblData.*
FROM    tblData
WHERE   pk <= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND
    CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013'
UNION
SELECT  TOP 10 tblData.*
FROM    tblData
WHERE   pk >= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND
    CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013') A
ORDER BY pk ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TOP 10 tblData.*
    FROM    tblData
    WHERE   dev_ID = @x AND code_ID = @y and date = @someDate
    ORDER BY PK DESC
union 
SELECT  TOP 10 tblData.*
    FROM    tblData
    WHERE   dev_ID = @x AND code_ID = @y and date = @someDate
    ORDER BY PK ASC
```

Comment: Thank lyou for your repsonse but, this does not appear to work, incorrect syntax near UNION and it does not locate the records 10 before and 10 after the pk identified.

Comment: I checked and union does not like order. But I cannot figure how the  individual sorts are not working?